# Backspace behavior in interactive shell

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the Scala interactive shell, but the backspace key's behavior is strange.  I'm finding that backspace does seem to delete the previous character, but it doesn't display that way on the line I'm typing... the cursor moves forward instead of backward.  This makes it impossible to see what the current input line looks like.

I'm using Scala 2.11.12.  I'm working in a terminal window on a Linux system, but xrdp'ing into the Linux host from a Windows 10 laptop.  The backspace key works fine outside Scala (in zsh).

As a workaround, is there any control character that tells Scala to redisplay the current line?  (Old OS's used to support characters that perform that function, if memory serves, but they haven't been necessary for a couple decades or so.)

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem and improved by changing the setting of pyenv.

If the global setting of `pyenv` is not system, try changing to system.

Example:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/*****/.pyenv/version)
  2.7.10
  3.5.0
  anaconda3-5.2.0
```

Comment: How does pyenv cause this Scala issue?

Comment: The same problem too. I search a lot and find no answer, then I comment out the zshrc files line by line and find `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` cause the problem.

This will set `PATH` to `~/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...`, and if `~/.pyenv/shims` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in `PATH`, there will be problem in scala shell.

Someone know how to make an issue to the pyenv people or scala people? It's a strange and very annoying bug...

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by scala instead of pyenv, because other interactive shells, such as ipython, irb, work just fine.

Comment: I post an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a bug of [JLine](https://jline.github.io/), which scala use as a replacement of readline. But, if I empty the folder `~/.pyenv/shims`, scala works fine. Then I execute `pyenv rehash` (which will bring back the files under `shims`), scala failed!

Then I remove the files in `~/.pyenv/shims` half by half and it's a file named **infocmp** makes the difference.  And it's not the content in it, but the exec permission that matters, i.e. `chmod a-x ~/.pyenv/shims/infocmp` will make scala work fine, but `chmod a+x ~/.pyenv/shims/infocmp`, even if infocmp is empty, the problem will occur!

May be I am close to the truth, but for now we can use `chmod a-x ~/.pyenv/shims/infocmp` to work around. And it needs only to be run once, because `pyenv rehash` will not overwrite a file if it already exists.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your great detective work. There is an issue on the pyenv project now and I just submitted a PR to fix this. It actually occurs for me also with asdf but I haven't tracked down a way to fix it yet. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1085

Comment: I don't have a ~/.pyenv/shims directory. Is this hiding in conda somewhere? I'm working purely in OS X.